# Evernote Java API java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when calling listNotebooks

Tags: java, api, out-of-memory, evernote

I am trying to obtain list of notes for my web app. I am using NoteStoreClient to obtain list on Notebooks then list of notes for every found notebook.

Here is my method constucting the client (actually the client wrapper, but that is just implementation details):

```
private DatesAwareNoteStoreClient fromAccessToken(EvernoteAccount evernoteAccount) throws TException, EDAMUserException, EDAMSystemException {
    // Set up the UserStore client and check that we can speak to the server
    synchronized (this) {
        EvernoteAuth evernoteAuth = new EvernoteAuth(EvernoteService.SANDBOX, evernoteAccount.getAccessToken());
        evernoteAuth.setNoteStoreUrl(evernoteAccount.getNoteStoreUrl());

        com.evernote.clients.ClientFactory factory = new com.evernote.clients.ClientFactory(evernoteAuth);

        // Set up the NoteStore client
        return new DatesAwareNoteStoreClient(factory.createNoteStoreClient());
    }
}
```

All works fine, I'm getting access token before, constructing of NoteStoreClient goes succesfully. But when I'm calling listNotebooks() I get very odd for me error:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Exception in thread "http-bio-2990-exec-11" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.evernote.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:388)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.evernote.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:236)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.recv_listNotebooks(NoteStore.java:337)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.listNotebooks(NoteStore.java:322)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.evernote.clients.NoteStoreClient.listNotebooks(NoteStoreClient.java:173)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.room606.jira.activenotes.evernote.EvernoteManager.listNotesByQuery(EvernoteManager.java:130)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.room606.jira.activenotes.evernote.EvernoteManager.listNotes(EvernoteManager.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.room606.jira.activenotes.action.StartReindexAction.doReindex(StartReindexAction.java:79)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.util.InjectionUtils$DefaultInjectionImpl.invoke(InjectionUtils.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.util.InjectionUtils.invoke(InjectionUtils.java:56)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.action.ActionSupport.invokeCommand(ActionSupport.java:438)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.action.ActionSupport.execute(ActionSupport.java:157)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.action.JiraActionSupport.execute(JiraActionSupport.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:39)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.NestedInterceptorChain.proceed(NestedInterceptorChain.java:31)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.ChainedInterceptor.intercept(ChainedInterceptor.java:16)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:35)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:225)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:154)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.dispatcher.JiraWebworkActionDispatcher.service(JiraWebworkActionDispatcher.java:152)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.XContentTypeOptionsNoSniffFilter.doFilter(XContentTypeOptionsNoSniffFilter.java:22)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
```

Here is my method causing original exception from stacktrace:

```
private Map<Notebook, List<NoteEntry>> listNotesByQuery(String filterQuery) throws EDAMUserException, EDAMSystemException, TException, EDAMNotFoundException {
    // First, get a list of all notebooks
    List<Notebook> notebooks = datesAwareNoteStoreClient.getClient().listNotebooks();

    Map<Notebook, List<NoteEntry>> noteEntriesMap = new HashMap<Notebook, List<NoteEntry>>();
    for (Notebook notebook : notebooks) {
        System.out.println("Notebook: " + notebook.getName());
        NoteFilter filter = new NoteFilter();
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filterQuery)) {
            filter.setWords(filterQuery);
        }
        filter.setNotebookGuid(notebook.getGuid());

        filter.setOrder(NoteSortOrder.CREATED.getValue());
        filter.setAscending(true);

        NoteList noteList = datesAwareNoteStoreClient.getClient().findNotes(filter, 0, 100);
        List<Note> notes = noteList.getNotes();
        noteEntriesMap.put(notebook, convertToNoteEntries(notebook.getName(), notes));
    }
    latestUpdateDate = new Date();

    return noteEntriesMap;
}
```

This line causes an error:

```
    // First, get a list of all notebooks
    List<Notebook> notebooks = datesAwareNoteStoreClient.getClient().listNotebooks();
```

What goes wrong and what am I missing in my obtan notes process? Thanks in advance!

I'm using Java JDK 1.6_045, Windows 7 x64, Evernote Java API version 2.5.1.

Comment: What I would do first is checking the configuration of the app server. Did he get enough memory and how much is free. Then I would try to find a way to check out the size of the result from listNotebooks(). Possible the result set is to big for your dev environment. Is there a way to count and chunk the result of listNotebooks()? If so do it, its always good to handle large resultsets in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha! I focused my attention on setting url method:

```
evernoteAuth.setNoteStoreUrl(evernoteAccount.getNoteStoreUrl());
```

What I was setting as note store url was a bullshit (authorize url, actually), so when just built a client without any additional data I got success! I wonder, that I got some oom error from as I assume server side wrapped in exception error. No memory consumption peaks was found by me locally.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to the JVM setting, so you will get a dump when this error happens. Then you can analyze the dump with MAT ([Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://eclipse.org/mat/)) . It will show where this error comes from - which data structure consumes the memory and where it referred from.